# ASCII code to Audio

Tags: audio, binary, ascii

I want to generate audio from ASCII code but I'm unable to do so.

I have used software MIDI to generate but want to know if there is some other software or programming language which can help me generate audio from ASCII or Binary??

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. What sort of "ASCII code" are you expecting to take as input?

Comment: You say you are "unable to do so".  Without seeing your code attempts, we can't help fix your approach.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not completely clear what you want to accomplish, since most audio formats use some kind of binary format.

Programs like [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org) are able to import raw binary data and then save it to a WAV/mp3 file. It is also possible to load and play back binary audio data in MATLAB.

If you need a more specific answer you have to provide more specific information about your input format.